# Yasnippets gives an unclear error (with example snippet)

Tags: yasnippet

I have the following snippet for PHP-mode, called *Public*.

```
#contributor : ReneFroger
#name : snippet for public 
# --

# --------------------------------------------------
#  Method f${2:name}.
# --------------------------------------------------
/* R.F: $1
```

When I load the snippet into the buffer with PHP-mode, and I type a long sentence (the sentence is longer than the lines (----) as above). Then I get an error message from Yasnippet in another buffer:

> Warning (yasnippet): Couldn’t find: "[[:space:] ]*#[[:space:]
>   ]*--------------------------------------------------[[:space:]
>   ]*#[[:space:] ]*Method[[:space:] ]*fname\.[[:space:] ]*#[[:space:]
>   ]*--------------------------------------------------[[:space:]
>   ]*/\*[[:space:] ]*R\.F:[[:space:] ]*\(\)[[:space:]
>   ]*This[[:space:] ]*is[[:space:] ]*an[[:space:] ]*error[[:space:]
>   ]*that[[:space:] ]*gives[[:space:] ]*a[[:space:] ]*weird[[:space:]
>   ]*error[[:space:] ]*in[[:space:] ]*Yasnippet[[:space:]
>   ]*with[[:space:] ]*unclear" Warning (yasnippet): Couldn’t find:
>   "[[:space:] ]*#[[:space:]

Before the regular packages update from Melpa (with Yasnippet included), I used this snippet a lot of time and never got this kind of error message.

It seems when entering a space, cause an error with Yasnippet. I googled around, but I couldn't find any explanation why spaces gives troubles with Yasnippet.

Anyone feeling to try this?

Comment: Sounds like [yasnippet/issues#794](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues/794). What yasnippet version are you using? Do you have `auto-fill-mode` enabled?

Comment: Disabling `auto-fill-mode` for PHP-mode helped, I don't get any error messages. Is it possible to combine Yasnippet with `auto-fill-mode` as in the past? I use Yasnippet version 0.11 by the way. .

Comment: You install from MELPA right? What timestamp does the package have? Does updating help?

Comment: `(advice-add 'yas--auto-fill-wrapper :override #'ignore)` solved my problem. I install from MELPA, indeed. To be sure, I removed the directory Yasnippet and installed it again from MELPA. And I get still the same problem as described above without the advice. Timestamp of yasnippet package is `yasnippet-20170418.351`.